# YouTube video in page embeded in iframe not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I assume this is a bug in Firefox, but just thought I would check here.

I have an iframe on my web page that contains a page that contains an embedded you tube player (inside an iframe). This works OK in Firefox.

However, when I add the following CSS rule:

```
iframe {
  transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
  -moz-transform: scale(.75, .75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(.75, .75);
  -o-transform: scale(.75, .75);
  -ms-transform: scale(.75, .75);
}
```

to the outer iframe, the YouTube video stops working in Firefox only. It works in Chrome, Opera and Safari.

Is this a Firefox bug?

Here is a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/6C65Y/28/

Comment: you can pass the size to the iframe : `width="560" height="315"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that firefox doesn't manages CSS scale on iframe.

This code will work :

```
var previewFrame = document.getElementById('test');
var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
preview.open();

var code = '<!doctype html><title>Test</title><h1>YouTube video</h1><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/64qx95Ckrwc" width="75%" height="75%"></iframe>';

preview.write(code);
preview.close();
```

​

Comment: I assume that is a bug in Firefox. There is actually a lot more on my page and I need to scale the iframe dynamically depending on the size of the browser.